# Why isn't the function parameter showing in the dialog?

Tags: sapui5

The function parameter that is a string isn't showing in the dialog content block. I need to know why and how to make this work. The parameter I am trying to show is string with php code.

I have used MessageToast.show() in my function to view the output string. The output string shows up. I have also tried adding "hello world" string the content block and that works.

Here is my code logic is a string.

```
logicDialog: function (logic) {
            MessageToast.show(logic);
            var dialog = new Dialog({
                title: 'Boolean Logic',
                type: 'Message',
                content: new TextArea({
                    value: logic,
                    editable: false,
                    growing: true,
                    growingMaxLines: 20

                }),
                beginButton: new Button({
                    text: 'Close',
                    press: function () {
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                }),
                afterClose: function () {
                    dialog.destroy();
                }
            });
            dialog.open();
        }
```

The expected result is dialog that shows the string logic.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/px7gyvr0/. What is the result you get; an empty dialog?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the example of @TiiJ7 works fine I will just try to throw some possible issues:

> -is your Dialog a sap.m.Dialog()?;
>
> -is there any error before the dialog is triggered? (that could somehow stop the functionality of the dialog);
>
> -put a break point in the line of "dialog.close();" to check the content of the string on the scope of the dialog opened;
>
> -is it possible that the string is being manipulated somewhere else and it could a be an issue with concurrency? 1 thread could be changing the value of the string (note that a string is a pointer).

I hope these points could bring you light, since you are the only one with access to the entire code.